# Is it possible upload files in model (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel

as I asked in the title, can it be done in model ?

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

    $file= $request->file('file');

    $path= Storage::disk('public')->putFile('/', new 
    File($file));

    $dB->path = $path;

    $db->save();
}
```

Comment: In model we generally store at value in table column which is name of file. and yes you can make a function to store file. just make  object of that model and call that function.

Comment: I can't call any function in controller because the process in the controller is "Model::update($validated)". Therefore this process should be automatic in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model:

```
public function insertFile($file) {
    if($this->path) {
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($this->path)
    }
    $path= Storage::disk('public')->putFile('/', new File($file));
    $this->path = $path;
    $this->save();
}
```

In your controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $db->insertFile($request->file('file');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, How can we also eliminate processing in the controller ?

Comment: How is the model supposed to know it should update if you don't tell it from the controller? You can reduce the code in the controller, not fully eliminate it (unless you put it into a middleware, but you would just move the code from the controller to the middleware)

Comment: Validation rules come with request to controller. The process in the controller is "Model::update($validated)". But i can't control the uploaded file.

Comment: It can't be done because `Model::update()` simply executes the query to the db, while saving a file requires you to actually handle where the file should go. You need to add at least 1 line to your controller (and honestly I can't understand why it should be a problem)

Comment: Let me ask this, can i do validated file upload process after Model:update() process ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your answers my friend, have a good day.